# Trying to store image

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i'm trying to store my quizzes image it's uploads image but i can't found image in my project folder but in database i can see that in image field there is uploaded image image.jpg
Then i added this

```
request()->file('image')->store('public/quizzes');
```

But now i'm getting error  Call to a member function store() on null

full store function:

```
 public function store(Quizze $quizzes)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'quizzes.title' => 'required',
            'quizzes.image' => '',
            'questions.*.question' => 'required',
            'questions.*.answers.*.answer' => 'required',
            'questions.*.answers.*.correct' => '',
        ], [
            'quizzes.title.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ ქვიზის სახელი.',
            'questions.*.question.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ შეკითხვა.',
            'questions.*.answers.*.answer.required' => 'გთხოვთ, შეიყვანოთ პასუხი.'
        ]);
        request()->file('image')->store('public/quizzes');
        $storeQuiz = $quizzes->create($data['quizzes']);
        foreach ($data['questions'] as $key => $q) {
            $question = $storeQuiz->questions()->create(['question' => $q['question']]);
            $question->answers()->createMany($data['questions'][$key]['answers']);
        }
        return redirect('admin/quizzes')->with('success', 'ქვიზი წარმატებით დაემატა.');
    }
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you try before storing image dd($request->hasFile == "image") if it is not null Storage::disk("your disk")->put('public/quizzes');

Comment: But i don't have $request i don't user Request  i try dd(request()->file('image')); but nothing is showing up

Comment: How did you configured your storage? Have you used `php artisan storage:link` command?

Comment: Sure /project/storage/app/public/quizzes where image must store

Comment: make sure that your image is coming or not

Comment: my image stores in this line with title $storeQuiz = $quizzes->create($data['quizzes']);  but  in this it's note coming request()->file('image')->store('public/quizzes');

Comment: So you can find the uploaded files in destination folder right? It means the problem is in viewing your image not in storing?

Comment: Its create in image filed  someimage.jpg but i can't find that kind of image in my project folder so i think it's only stores image name not a image

Answer (score 0):

you can store image by following way

```
if($request->image != null)
{
   $image = request()->file('avatar');
   $image->move(public_path('/images/'),$request->image->getClientOriginalName());
}
```